# Emulating Python zip() Function

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm brushing up on Python, working my way through [Python Workout](https://www.manning.com/books/python-workout). One of the exercises is to emulate the Python zip() function, assuming each iterable passed to the function is of the same length. Here's what I've come up with:

```
def myzip(*args):
    result = [[] for _ in range(len(args[0]))]
    for i, v in enumerate(args):
        for j, w in enumerate(v):
            result[j].append(w)

    for i, v in enumerate(result):
        result[i] = tuple(v)

    return result
```

While my function works, I have a hunch there must be a more succinct way of achieving the same thing (forgoing the nested loops). Is there? I'm running Python 3.9.

Answer (score 7):

You should not apply `len`, because that requires that the first argument be at least as strong as a `Collection`, when `zip` should not need that guarantee and should only need `Iterable` which is a weaker type.

Gathering results in memory can be inefficient and lead to memory starvation. It's worth noting that an in-memory approach might actually execute more quickly than a generator but you would want to test this.

Attempt some type hinting. The amount of type-hinting you can do here is fairly limited, but you can do better than nothing.

It's also worth noting that the [official documentation has a reference implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

### Suggested

```
from typing import Any, Iterable, Tuple


def myzip(*args: Iterable[Any]) -> Iterable[Tuple[Any, ...]]:
    first_iter, *other_iters = (iter(a) for a in args)

    for first in first_iter:
        yield (first, *(
            next(other) for other in other_iters
        ))


for a, b in myzip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]):
    print(a, b)
```

### Alternate

This version does not need to wrap the first argument in an iterator.

```
def myzip(first_iter: Iterable[Any], *args: Iterable[Any]) -> Iterable[Tuple[Any, ...]]:
    others = [iter(a) for a in args]

    for first in first_iter:
        yield (first, *(
            next(other) for other in others
        ))
```